# HTML Canvas remove letter spacing on the beginning of a word

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas and I want to print words on it in horizontal and vertical orientation. The printing itself works fine but I have a somewhat annoying spacing at the beginning of the words, which becomes extremely visible on the vertical text like the EX on the example image.

[image]

I just created a little example which shows what I mean

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Create a red line in position 150
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.moveTo(150, 20);
ctx.lineTo(150, 170);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.font = "50px Arial";    

// Show the different textAlign values
ctx.textAlign = "start";      
ctx.fillText("EX", 150, 50);        
ctx.textAlign = "end";      
ctx.fillText("EX", 150, 100);                  
ctx.textAlign = "center";         
ctx.fillText("EX", 150, 150);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Is there a way to place the beginning of the word at the point I am drawing to or is there a way to calculate the spacing at the beginning and then just subtract it from the starting point of the text?

Comment: I can see only a few pixels of "prefix" in the code snippet rendering, but i can see how it can be annoying. It may depend on the font (try some monospace font). Have you tried https://opentype.js.org/ to get full control over rendering of characters?

Comment: @ahwayakchih this looks interesting. If I understand it correctly, with this I can get the path of the word and print that to the canvas, correct?

Comment: Is this a feature of a particular font? In the snippet the base of the X slightly overlaps the red line which looks as though it means the top part of the X is deliberately designed not to be directly vertically above it. A serif font touched the line on the left at least on my system.

Comment: the `fillText` command places text based on the _text's_ bounding box. Not the _vector outline_ bounding box, so it's pretty much useless if you need pixel perfect alignment: text (including single letters) almost always have left side-bearing spacing (as well as right side-bearing spacing). So yeah: use OpenType.js or the like if you need to align text "as if it's just graphics data", because as text data it's guaranteed going to be wrong. (Especially text with long ascenders/descenders or swashes go _terribly_ wrong)

Comment: @Bongo yes, there's a nice example code and API info on their GitHub page. You may need to call `Path.getBoundingBox()` for the path you get, to check if it has x1 > 0, but i'm not sure. API looks pretty easy to use, so just try and see :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TextMetrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) interface has `actualBoundingBox[...]` information that you can use to know by how much the actual bounding box is offset relatively to the `textAlign` and `textBaseline` lines.

So adding the measured `actualBoundingBoxLeft` to your horizontal position when writing LTR text with the `"start"` *text-align* will remove this gap.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.oninput = draw;
draw();

function draw() {
  const txt = input.value;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  // Create a red line in position 150
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.moveTo(150, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(150, 180);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.font = "50px Arial";    
  ctx.textBaseline = "top"; // needed for the ascent and decsent measurements

  // Show the original textAlign
  ctx.textAlign = "start";      
  ctx.fillText(txt, 150, 30);        

  // fixed
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  const metrics = ctx.measureText(txt);
  ctx.fillText(txt, 150 + metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft, 110);

  // Draw the box around our text
  ctx.translate( 150, 110 );
  const x = 0; // we already did offset by actualBoundingBoxLeft
  const y = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent * -1;
  const width = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight + metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft;
  const height = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent + metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent;
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input value="Éxy"><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```